# Accessing multi JSONs

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

In the console of the browser I have this: [image]

This is returned by this AJAX:

```
function displayFiles(){
var classElements = document.querySelectorAll("table.folders-list tr.ui-selected td span");
var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();
for(var x = 0;x < classElements.length;x++){
    var result;
    result = classElements[x].innerHTML;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,                      
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '../public/getfiles',
        data: { 'folder': result, "_token": csrf  },
        success: function(data) {
        }
    });
}; 
}
```

I want to access them. Tried `console.log(data[0].filename);` but got an error.
When there is a single JSON I get `TypeError: data[0] is undefined`, while if there are more than one (just like in the pic) nothing is returned.
And this is the PHP function that sends that objects:

```
public function getFiles() {
    $folder = $_POST['folder'];
    $userid = Auth::id();
    $query = File::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('userid', $userid)->where('folder', $folder)->get();
    // foreach for many result returned by $query
    foreach($query as $result){
        $arr = array();
        $arr['filename'] = $result->filename;
        $arr['id'] = $result->fileid;
        $arr['size'] = $result->conv_filesize;
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }      
}
```

Comment: What error did you get? Please try to be as specific as possible with the code you tried and the exact message it gave.

Comment: @IMSoP updated the question

Comment: You are send two different JSONObject? why? You can send JSONArray with those JSONObject right? btw, which programming language u r using for the server side? PHP?

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed Yeah PHP, look, updated the question again

Comment: Your PHP code looks wrong to me: it will result in something like `{"id": 1}{"id": 2}`, which is invalid JSON; you should be putting the items into an array, and calling `json_encode` once at the end, so that you get something like `[{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]`

Comment: @Alex hope your problem solved. Always remember to post your codes so it will be easy for us to figure out the problem. The problem is not in your JavaScript but in your PHP script :-)

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed Yeah, it is solved. Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are putting multiple JSON strings just next to each other. This in turn is no valid JSON.

Your output looks something like `{"x": 1}{"y": 2}`, where it needs to be `[{"x": 1},{"y": 2}]`.

Try outputting all your data in a single call to `json_encode()`:

```
public function getFiles() {
    $folder = $_POST['folder'];
    $userid = Auth::id();
    $query = File::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('userid', $userid)->where('folder', $folder)->get();
    // foreach for many result returned by $query
    $json = array();
    foreach($query as $result){
        $arr = array();
        $arr['filename'] = $result->filename;
        $arr['id'] = $result->fileid;
        $arr['size'] = $result->conv_filesize;
        $json[] = $arr;
    }    
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

You might also try a JSON validator. ;)

Comment: `json[] = $arr;` gives an `unexpected = after ]`

Comment: you forgot the `$` in front of json[]; This may be a solution to my problem

Comment: Ugh, yeah. Fixed that. Thx